# Correct XPath but sendKeys() not working in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to send text to the password field at `https://signup.live.com/` however while all other fields are populated correctly (and the `XPath` for password field is also correct -- `.//*[@id='Password']`) the data doesn't show up for in the password and password confirmation fields.

I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that after sending email/user name the page (sort of) refreshes (it displays "this username is available" or "unavailable") but this only effects the password fields..

I am not sure how to resolve the issue as the `XPath` I'm using is correct..

Any ideas?

Thanks

P.S

Some people say the email validation is causing the error which is probably correct. However when I add:

```
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

it does not seem to fix the issue. Sometimes it works, most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: try putting some wait before entering password.

Comment: @Kapil He did  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

It causing problem due to email validation. Once you send an email the site validates and selenium tries to send password meanwhile  but couldn't find the  element focused and throws So it couldn't focus on password field and throws :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: cannot focus element

So before sending password you have to put some wait until the emailid get validated (analyze how much time it takes to validate email) and then send your password. Here `Thread.sleep()` will help you to do so. but some time its not recommended because it pause your script for given time event your element intractable before given time.

Another recommendation is if you have element id then avoid to use xpath you can locate same like `driver.findElement(By.id("Password"))`.

For your script sample code can be :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();    
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://signup.live.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("test");
driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("user");
driver.findElement(By.id("MemberName")).sendKeys("testuser@gmail.com");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("testone1#");
driver.findElement(By.id("RetypePassword")).sendKeys("testone1#");
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is a bad practice. You should be using `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: @JeffC, can you post your answer with `webdriverwait` condition to handle can not focus element error. Use the same URL as OP posted. And I think it's a bed practice that every time when you see thread.sleep in selenium post, you prefer down vote

Comment: I tried it and I"m not seeing any issues at all. The question is unclear what the issue is and no code is provided so it's hard to tell what's actually going on.`Thread.sleep()` is a well documented bad practice so when you, or anyone else, puts that in their answer it should get downvoted unless you explain why it's absolutely necessary in that particular case.

Comment: @JeffC, I'm not seeing alternative other then thread.sleep here can u please use the code snippet I 'm using in my answer and let me know if you are able to send password without thread.sleep or some explicit wait. Conditions

Comment: @Tuks You're answer probably correct. However, when I add:

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


it does not seem to fix the issue. Sometimes it works, most of the time it doesn't.